# How to tell unison the local replica is just local (doesn't matter what hostname)?

Tags: sync, unison

I've been having this problem for a while.

My unison profile says:

```
root = /Users/mylogin
root = ssh://mylogin@mydesktop//home/myloign
```

I run Unison from everywhere in the world to sync against my Desktop, but sometimes the local network gives my Macbook a funny hostname, like: `1223.youarehere.com`.

In such cases Unison says this is the 1st time I attempt to sync them, and try to start over.

What can I do?

I just want local replica to be **the** local replica.

Comment: If you find a solution yourself, post it as an "answer" below.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the environment variable UNISONLOCALHOSTNAME to your prefered local host name.
For example,

```
export UNISONLOCALHOSTNAME=mylaptop.
```